# how to convert int to NSTimeInteravl in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, typeconverter, nstimeinterval

Please do tel me how to convert int to NSTimeInterval?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is just a typedef for double.  Feel free to assign the int to the NSTimeIntervalValue the same way you can assign an int to a double.